# Re-insertion of user inputted values. php or .post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, database, forms

This question might sound a little amatuer but just curious to find out.

So i've got a form field that consists of mixed text-boxes, selectboxes and textareas. It stores its user-inputted values in the database and have the values re-inserted everytime user wants to re-edit the form.

My question is for the re-insertion process of the form fields via stored values in my database, is it better to use 1) php mysql queries or 2) doing a .post that calls another script, json-encode the data and using jquery to insert the values into the form on .ready?

I would appreciate if someone would be able advise me the better way to do it and explain the complications of each method. Like say, which method would you choose and why would you choose it?

Would it incur more bandwidth? disk space on my host computer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Either way is valid, but I personally would go with the PHP approach.  The reason for this is if you do it via AJAX then you're form will load and a second later your fields will populate.  That doesn't feel very professional and damages the customer experience. Whereas with PHP prebuilding the data, the form is already built and ready to go =)

As far as optimization, it's going to be un-noticable on the PHP side. But they will certainly notice un-populated fields suddenly being populated.

Comment: Moreover, if JS is not activated, your form will not be filled.... its bad, its not unobstrusive.